How to correct script which get emails of users?
I try to get eMails of users which change any range in my Google Sheets.
I use this script below:
function onEdit(event) {
  var as = event.source.getActiveSheet();//Текущий лист
  var address = event.range.getA1Notation().toUpperCase();//Адрес ячейки
  var row = event.range.getRow();      //Номер строки
  var col = event.range.getColumn();  //Номер столбца
  var newValue = event.value;            //Новое значение
  var oldValue = event.oldValue;        //Старое значение
  var userEmail = event.user.getEmail();//Пользователь(работает только при вручную назначенном триггере)

  let archiveSheetName = "reg";
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let archiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName(archiveSheetName) || ss.insertSheet(archiveSheetName);
  archiveSheet.appendRow([new Date(), userEmail, as.getName(), address, oldValue, newValue]);
};

But it works only when owner (me) change anythink in Google Sheets. When i test and change the user account (for example to xxxx@gmail.com), the script dont get this user eMail (xxxx@gmail.com). But i give for this user (xxxx@gmail.com) all permission in Google Shet.
I know, i can use Trigger by other account (xxxx@gmail.com) and it really work. But script give me double value. (1 - eMail "xxxx@gmai.com", 2 - empty value). If i use Trigger by more users (xxxx2@gmail.com - xxxxN@gmail.com), script get more EMPTY value. And its not good for me.
Look at screen below:


Why not [edit] the question to also include the script that works but returns a double value. Why not just commit the populated email address value to the spreadsheet and omit the empty one?
